# What is the best way to display JSON response in HTML div?

Tags: html, json

I have a URL that returns the following JSON response (for multiple restaurants). What is the simplest way to parse the response and display individual fields in a HTML page?

```
[
  {
    restaurant_name: 'R_name',
    address: {
      longitude: -121.483693,
      city: 'City Name',
      zip: '00000',
      latitude: 317.328255,
      state: 'ZZ',
      street_address: 'Street Address',
    },
    menu_data: [
      'Zereshk',
      'Khoreshe Ghorm-E-Sabszi with Beef',
      'Khoreshe Gheym-Budemjan with Beef',
      'Khoreshe Gheym with Beef',
      'Khoreshe Fesenjan with Breast Chicken',
      'Khoreshe Karafs with Beef',
      'Boneless Jujeh Kabob (Chicken)',
      'Kobedeh Kabob (Ground Beef)',
      'Potato Salad with Chicken',
      'Salad Olvieh with Lavash',
      'Kashk-E-Budemjan(Egg Plant Dip)',
      'Grilled Eggplant with Nuts',
      'Grape Leaf Stuffed with Our Special Vegetable and Rice and Fresh Herbs',
      'Koukou Sabzi (Mediterranean Quiche)',
      'Hummus',
      'Babaghanouge',
      'Cucumber Yogurt Mix',
      'Shallot Yogurt Mix',
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: $("document").ready(function() {
                $.getJSON("http://localhost:63342/295%20Project/api/response.json?", function(result){
                    $.each(result, function(i, field){
                        $("div").append(field.toString() + " ");
                    });
                });
            });

Comment: but this only displays [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]

Comment: How can I print the content of the Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to go about it. You're already getting the response in JSON format, now you just need to iterate over the keys and create a template string out of it and later create an html from the same. To give the most basic method:

You can use `Object.keys()` (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the array of keys from the object. Now you can loop over these keys, append the values and create a template string/literals (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Then you can add this element as an inner html of some div that you already have.
Now this is the most basic method. Obviously you can optimise the number of steps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a google chrome extension JSON Formatter [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en), that can be used to desplay a user-friendly json.  Are you desplaying json for debugging purpurse?

Comment: I need to display the JSON in an HTML page. Kinda new to web development, doing it for a project.

Comment: Once you have the json object content. you can desplay its content the way you want. you can use css or boostrap. you can even put it inside an html table and use the style you want

Comment: Can you please provide some examples?